How to copy label with name - Visual Studio 2022
I created a new label. It came with "label1" name.
I changed the name "label1" to "myLabel1".
I'm copying this: "myLabel1"
When I paste it comes as: "label1"
It wasn't like this before.
When I paste must be like this:
"myLabel1", "myLabel2", "myLabel3", "myLabel4"
I looked in visual studio settings but didn't see anything.
click for example image
